Help! The 22.04 to 24.04 LTS upgrade didn't complete!
The upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS (i.e., latest) didn't finish well.  After downloading everything, and while upgrading packages, something went wrong and the upgrade halted.
Now, I'm left with a system that wouldn't restart.  When I forced the computer to shut down, it wouldn't get to the login screen.
Can I salvage the upgrade?!  Is there something I can do from the maintenance screen?!
Thanks a lot in advance.
Hosam Adeeb Nashed

It is now I am doing one as we speak after the prompt came up on 3 of my 6 machines.

Since my upgrade from 22.04.4 to 24.04.1  just finished I would have to say yes you were mistaken. I did have to run a fix broken install after

You're right, 24.04.1 is released - my mistake.

Either that or I dreamed the last 2 hours watching the upgrade. lol Had to run an update of the snaps after the reboot that I did after the fix broken install

Presumably you backed everything up before attempting upgrade - it is probably easier to perform a fresh install of 24.04 and then reinstate your data rather than try to salvage the failed upgrade.

"something went wrong and the upgrade halted" is too vague to offer useful advice. Seeing the actual error(s), in the proper context, from your logs would be very helpful. Without detail, all we can recommend is a new-install.

From a live session, chroot and repair the installation. Search the forum for how to do this.

Same problem here.
This is how i managed to get my system going again.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery
